# Vue loading component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to implement a loading functionality to a component.

My fisrt idea was to make a HOC (high-order-component)  that would receive its content in the  and just be responsible for managing the loading state and its text, plus that no click events pass thru.

```
<loading-hoc :active="loading">
    <my-component></my-component>
</loading-hoc>
```

I implemented this and in the Vue dev tools I get this:

[image]

Then I looked around and found ElementUI's implementation which is a directive and adds a DOM element to the current component which looks like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ys1zvq2n/).

#### Question:

What are the pros and cons of the different approaches? Is there a correct way to do it?

As I see it:

a) Using as a HOC:

- verbose tree in the dev-tools (minus)

b) using directive

- DOM nodes being added into a component from outside the component (minus)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be is adding a property loading initialized to `true` in data property and use this to control visibility of the loading element using `v-if`

Simple demo:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-if="loading" class="loading">Loading...</div>

    <h5>{{content}}</h5>
</div>
```

**script**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        content: null,
        loading: true
    },
    mounted(){
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.content= 'Data fetched from external server od database';
            this.loading = false;
        },3000);

        //if you had a data fetching api like axios, set the loading to false in the success callback handler

        axios.get('/api').then( data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.loading = false;
        });
    }
})
```

Here is the demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lqwdsp/)

Comment: Your suggestion is a 3rd version, alike ElementUI's in the sense that the DOM element that has the loader is not in a DOM hierarchy relation to the content. That might give `z-index` and other position problems. If we have a HOC we can easy guarante we block pointer events and have control over the content because of DOM hierarchy. Does it make sense? what are your thoughts about that`?

Comment: @Rikard see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lqwdsp/1/  , the button cannot be clicked as the loading div is above it

Comment: Its very easy to get around that: https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lqwdsp/2/  I mean easy for other developers in the team to make small simple errors that will brake that.

Comment: @Rikard why not use a z-index on the loading div https://jsfiddle.net/n1Lqwdsp/3/

Comment: Because its very easy that someone puts "my z-index" + 1

Comment: @Rikard then use a arbitrary value like 10000 for z-index and add a unit test to check if any member sets z-index of other element than your loading element

Comment: I understand your point and its defenetly a way to go. But I think using a HOC and thus having DOM hierarchy control over the slots is more powerfull and error-safe.

Comment: @Rikard yup that could also be done....it all depends on the use case and which suits your purpose the best:)